# can i call my movieclip(parent).var using this code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

can i use MovieClip(parent).this["string"] to call a variable from parent movieclip

i have a var target1HP, target2HP to target6HP in the parent movieclip. i want to call target1HP

```
for (counter = 1; counter<=6; counter++) {
    if (MovieClip(parent).this["target"+counter+"HP"] == 0) {
         //do statement//
    }
}
```

is this possible or do i have to it manually like this?

```
    if (MovieClip(parent).target1HP == 0) {
         //do statement//
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
MovieClip(parent)["target"+counter+"HP"]
```

Comment: follow up question, can i use that code on the parent movieclip to check it's currentLabel? for example.

this is now the parent MovieClip:
childMovieClip.["target"+counter+"HP"].currentLabel?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve? `Target2HP` is a number, it doesn't have `currentLabel` property.

Comment: sorry typo. `childMovieClip.["target"+counter].currentLabel`

Comment: `childMovieClip["target"+counter].currentLabel` (no dot after childMovieClip).